# Входная строка имеет неверный формат C#

Tags: c#, типы-данных, vknet

combobox как вы знаете требует string, а Messages.GetChat - long.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ему всё конвентирую, он жалуется и жалуется.
Писать Convert.ToInt32 или Convert.ToInt64 разницы нет, всё та же ошибка.
Прошу помогите

Comment: а посмотреть что за строка у вас внутри `chat[i]` ни как? С чего вы взяли что там число? Выведите содержимое без преобразований хотя бы в MessageBox и посмотрите что там. а потом уже думайте как это конвертировать в то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Джентльмены находят, что замена картинки фрагментом воспроизводимого кода, способствует росту вероятности получить ответ.

Comment: Пространство имен на русском? Фии...

Comment: @iluxa1810: По названию приложения, очевидно.

Answer (score 0):

Весьма вероятно проблема заключается в том, что в Chats.txt находятся не только числа и поэтому Convert и выдает ошибку, но желательно бы увидеть содержимое данного файла для полного решения проблемы.